# Back compat for AccessibilityTraversalOrder

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-appcompat, accessibility

I'm trying to programmatically setAccessibilityTraversalOrder on a view in Android and it's working great for API level 22. I have a method, which I call to set the traversal order.

```
 @TargetApi(22)
  public static void setAccessibilityAfter(View view, int afterId) {
    view.setAccessibilityTraversalAfter(afterId);
  }
```

And then I set an AccessibilityDelegate like this.

```
 private static final AccessibilityDelegateCompat ACCESSIBILITY_DELEGATE_COMPAT =
      new AccessibilityDelegateCompat() {
        @Override
        public void onInitializeAccessibilityEvent(View host, AccessibilityEvent event) {
          super.onInitializeAccessibilityEvent(host, event);
          event.setClassName(Button.class.getName());
        }

        @Override
        public void onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(View host, AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat info) {
          super.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(host, info);
          info.setClassName(Button.class.getName());
        }
      };
```

I need to support minimum API version of 16 (JellyBean), thus this solution doesn't scale. So, I found out about AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat class. I tried to use that class like this in my helper method like this.

```
  public static void setAccessibilityAfter(View view, int afterId) {
    AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat info = AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat.obtain(view);
    ViewCompat.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(view, info);
    if (afterId != View.NO_ID) {
      View rootView = view.getRootView();
      if (rootView == null) {
        rootView = view;
      }
      View next = rootView.findViewById(afterId);
      if (next != null) {
        info.setTraversalAfter(next);
      }
    }
  }
```

There are 2 problems with this solution:
1: It doesn't work because as soon as a user touches that view on the screen, the delegate gets called again and initializes that node again, so I lose the traversalAfter value I set here. 
2: I'm also leaking a node here, which I'm not sure when to recycle.

Can anybody help me how I can hook Android backwards compatibility using NodeInfoCompat and AccessibilityDelegateCompat?

Answer (score 2):

OP I don't know what your alternate approach was, but this worked for me:

```
ViewCompat.setAccessibilityDelegate(mySecondView, new AccessibilityDelegateCompat() {
    @Override
    public void onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(View v, AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat info) {
        super.onInitializeAccessibilityNodeInfo(v, info);
        info.setTraversalAfter(myFirstView);
    }
});
```

However I did not test it on anything earlier than API 22, which @alanv claims won't work but I was not able to find anything to back his claim.

Comment: I tried ViewCompat.setAccessibilityDelegate on various APIs. API 21: doesn't work. API 23/24/25: works. So it seems that @alanv is right, it doesn't work for API < 22

Answer (score 1):

Calling `AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat.setTraversalBefore/After` has no effect on API < 22. The feature is not backported.

You will get the same effect from simply gating your call on `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 22`:

```
public static void setAccessibilityTraversalAfter(View view, int afterId) {
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 22) {
    view.setAccessibilityTraversalAfter(afterId);
  }
}
```

Comment: I also noticed that Google has this AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat class, which is a helper class to set API level 4 properties. This has setTraversalAfter and setTraversalBefore.  How else can I achieve custom focus on devices with API < 22. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/accessibility/AccessibilityNodeInfoCompat.html

Comment: I have a custom accessibility delegate. If I can catch FOCUS_FORWARD, FOCUS_BACKWARD events, I can force focus on a cached after, before view Id.

Comment: It sees like whenever talkBack is on and swipe left to go to the next element or swipe right to go to the previous element, no other event other than ACCESSIBILITY_FOCUSED or ACCESSIBILITY_FOCUS_CLEARED are getting called. @alan, is the any way to find out that user is trying to go to the next a11y element?

Comment: Hi @alanv, any thoughts? Apparently, there is no other way to detect swipe right/left gestures and do something except in AccessibilityService. And to do that, I need to write my custom accessibility service.

Comment: As stated in the answer, the feature is not supported prior to API 22. There is no reliable workaround that can be used to implement the feature in earlier OS versions. If there were, it would have been implemented in the support library.

Comment: Thanks Alan. Yes, I figured. I took an alternate approach instead. I've marked it as complete.

Comment: @AmayKataria if you found an alternate approach, would you mind sharing it? Thanks.

Comment: @alanv can you tell us why you think it has no effect? I can't seem to find anything from Android docs that supports your statement.